# Calling my hosted API from AWS via a Lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have an API that is currently secured by Identity server 3.
We are moving to AWS Cognito to login.
When a user signs up, I need to call our current API to make sure their username is in our database. How do I do this with a lambda function?
And how can I secure our API (which is hosted on our server), with the Cognito auth?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pre-sign up lambda trigger on Cognito for check db.

Comment: I'm aware of that. But I'm not sure what that involves.Is it just a post API call? What do I need to do on my API to allow the lambda trigger access?

Comment: You should check your user credentials(username,e-mail) on your db before sign-up request with pre-sign up lambda. Pre-sign up lamda is just an API service and you could set these API service on your Cognito User Pool.